# TaskDialog doesn't work although runtime themes enabled

Tags: delphi, themes, ttaskdialog

I'm developing dll in Delphi 10.2, in which I'm using TTaskDialog.
TTaskDialog requires themes enabled.

Everything was working until few days ago. But now TTaskDialog doesn't show up at all and TTaskDialog.execute returns False.

I double(tripple) checked that I have Manifest File Auto Generate with Enable Runtime Themes checked on all configurations.
I can see also in dproj file that it is set to True.
I tried as well to create custom manifest file with version 6.0.0.0 of assemblyidentity.
I also tried suggestions from [Delphi runtime theme enabled, but not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101560/delphi-runtime-theme-enabled-but-not-used)
But my task dialogs do not work.

Checking out ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled returns False in any occasion.

Can anyone suggest directions?

Comment: Use a resource editor to inspect the manifest resource itself

Comment: If the you call the Win32 `TaskDialog/Indirect()` function directly, what `HRESULT` error code does it return?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I get -2147467263. In documentation says that TaskDialogIndirect  can return four values (S_OK, E_OUTOFMEMORY, E_INVALIDARG, E_FAIL), but nothing matches the answer I get.

Comment: @LenaGavrilov error code `-2147467263` (hex `0x80004001`) is HRESULT `E_NOTIMPL` ("Not implemented")

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstraes the issue.