# How to check if a style file is already loaded?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, vcl-styles

I have a ListBox that lists all style files (vsf) in a folder.
When the user clicks a file, I load that style:

```
 if TStyleManager.IsValidStyle(sSkinFile, StyleInfo) then
  begin
   TStyleManager.LoadFromFile(sSkinFile);
   TStyleManager.SetStyle(StyleInfo.Name);
  end
```

However, if the user clicks a style that was already loaded (was clicked previously), Delphi will rise and exception: "Style 'Golden Graphite' already registered".

Note: It looks like the system will not release the previous styles when a new style is loaded. I think that the memory consumption will be a bit higher if the user will start clicking all listed styles.

How do I check if a style was already loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Style`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.Style) property of the [`TStyleManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager), this property will return nil when a VCL Style is not loaded. Try this sample.

```
uses
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.Themes;

function  VCLStyleLoaded(StyleName : string) : Boolean;
begin
 Result := TStyleManager.Style[StyleName] <> nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 StyleInfo: TStyleInfo;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin        
    if TStyleManager.IsValidStyle(OpenDialog1.FileName, StyleInfo)  and not VCLStyleLoaded(StyleInfo.Name) then
    begin
     TStyleManager.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
     TStyleManager.SetStyle(StyleInfo.Name);
    end
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @rruz-Something weird I discovered today: TStyleManager.IsValidStyle always fails if Vcl.Styles is not in the USES list!!!! I mean, the program compiles without warnings; but the function fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `TStyleManager.TrySetStyle` and load the style only when it fails.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted. This method is counter intuitive. I was digging the Themes unit code for something more delphi-like such as: if not StyleRegistered(x) then LoadFromFile(y)                         :)

Comment: @TLama-It has to work with disk (vcf) files. But I got the idea. I can do it now. Many thanks. +1

Comment: You're welcome! The input of that function should suffice because you're obtainting the `StyleInfo` when calling `IsValidStyle`. Similar check is done internally and results in the `EDuplicateStyleException`.

Comment: As your code part activates the style after loading, I had the impression that the listbox selection should be activated anyway. Then a `if not TrySetStyle the begin LoadFromFile; SetStyle end;` looks quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Something weird I discovered today: TStyleManager.IsValidStyle always fails if Vcl.Styles is not in the USES list!!

---

SOLUTION: 
simply add Vcl.Styles to the Uses list.