# Form losses modal attribute after changing app style

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I create a modal form in which the user can set a (vcf) style.

I use this code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnChangeSkinClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmSkins:= TfrmSkins.Create(NIL);
  frmSkins.ShowModal;
end;

procedure TfrmSkins.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
 Action:= caFree;
end;
```

And then in frmSkins, I list all available vcf files in a list box. When the user clicks a style, I load that style like this:

```
procedure TfrmSkins.lBoxClick(Sender: TObject);
VAR  StyleInfo : TStyleInfo;
begin
    ...
    sSkinFile:= lBox.Items[lBox.ItemIndex];
    if TStyleManager.IsValidStyle(sSkinFile, StyleInfo) then
      begin
       TStyleManager.LoadFromFile(sSkinFile);
       TStyleManager.SetStyle(StyleInfo.Name);
      end;

    // this will 'fix' half of the problem, bringing the form up. But it won't make the form modal again.
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    BringToFront;
end;
```

After calling SetStyle, frmSkins is sent to back (under main form) and permanently looses the modal attribute!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At what point is that second block of code invoked? Why are you calling `Application.CreateForm`? Only call that for the main form. Why are you not using `try/finally`?

Comment: I guess that the window recreation code in the VCL fails to set the owner window correctly. Known as popup parent in VCL terminology. Would not be surprising for there to be a defect in VCL styles.

Answer (score 0):

This problem remains in Delphi Rio.3. There is only one real solution. Instead of using a modal form, create a mini-app that can't lose focus, allows the user to click the controls, and employ a Save button that will update the main app's registry. Then use some scheme in the main app to resume execution, read the registry, and TrySetStyle if needed.

Comment: isn't this a bit extreme?

Answer (score 0):

If the modal form is shown by your main form you can use this workaround:

```
type
  TChildForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TChildForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Application.MainForm.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TChildForm.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
    case Msg.Msg of
    CM_CUSTOMSTYLECHANGED:
    begin
        Application.MainForm.Enabled := false;
    end;
    end;
    inherited WndProc(Msg);
end;
```