# Modern view application with Delphi VCL. It's possibly?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I wanna modern view of my application on old systems like windows XP. How I can do it, without use FMX?

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: @JerryDodge might be forever alone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use VCL components with XE10, that provide you to use Native Extended Styles.

you can check this :

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/VCL_Styles_Overview

or

[Delphi XE2 VCL styles tutorial - how to change the style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906312/delphi-xe2-vcl-styles-tutorial-how-to-change-the-style-at-runtime)

however be carefull of which version of Delphi you are using, because embarcadero change a little bit about how the ***TStyleManager*** apply styles (pre-load, at run time, ressource... there is few way to apply it).

example :

```
var
  StyleResource : string; // filename of the style    
begin
  TStyleManager.LoadFromResource(HInstance, StyleResource);
```