# Windows Aero Peek showing only title bar when minimized

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-10-seattle, vcl-styles, aero-peek

Using Delphi 10 Seattle on Windows 10, as well as the Windows 10 Dark VCL Style. When the window is in its normal state, hovering over the taskbar icon shows the full window in the thumbnail. However, if I minimize my application, then hovering over the taskbar icon only shows the titlebar in the thumbnail. Further, if I hover over the thumbnail, the window preview also only shows the titlebar, nothing else. If I restore my window back to its natural state, everything works fine again.

I'm sure it has to do with the particular VCL style "Windows 10 Dark" because other VCL styles do not behave this way. In fact, without using VCL styles at all, the preview only shows the client area of the form, and doesn't show the titlebar at all. But using this style, all I can see is the titlebar.

Here's a *blank* form with *only* the "Windows 10 Dark" style applied, no code:

[image: Empty Form]

When the window is in its normal state, Aero Peek shows fine:

[image: Normal State]

And when it's in its minimized state, only shows title bar:

[image: Minimized State]

And when hovering over the minimized thumbnail, also only shows title bar:

[image: Preview]

As you can see, this completely defeats the purpose of Aero Peek. It looks like something is causing it to revert back to the ancient Windows 3.1 minimized window style.

I've installed the [`vcl-style-utils`](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils) library and tried the `Vcl.Styles.Fixes` unit, among others, but still no luck. This behavior is confirmed to occur on 4 different installations of Delphi 10 Seattle (Update 1).

What's causing this to happen and how can I make the preview work properly?

---

**EDIT**

When I said "It doesn't happen on other styles", this was not thoroughly proven. I was judging based on other apps which had previously been compiled in Delphi 10 Seattle. While in reality, actually *all* VCL styles are doing this. Without using any VCL Styles, everything works as expected.

To add, those pre-built applications which did not show such behavior also have these styles embedded and applied manually. Whereas, a new empty application exhibits this behavior by assigning the style through the IDE Project Options.

In light of this, I will further test to see if manually embedding/applying styles really does make a difference.

---

**EDIT 2**

As said, I tested a bit with manually assigning styles. After copying [the code in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9914235/988445), *after* switching off and back on the style in runtime, suddenly I no longer see this behavior. So it appears this issue only occurs when loading the default style. The pre-compiled applications I spoke of in prior edit all are designed to dynamically apply styles in runtime, regardless of the one set up in the IDE.

---

**EDIT 3**

Oddly, after it worked the first time after *EDIT 2*, now I cannot get it to work as expected again. Switching the style in runtime is no longer "fixing" this. It only seemed to "fix" it once. So why everything works fine in our production applications, is a matter of further investigation. Technically, those applications don't even have the styles embedded inside of them. They're actually embedded into a single DLL which is then shared by those applications, and their resources are extracted and applied in runtime. So I will have to dig in and try to re-create the working code.

Comment: Crappy VCL styles is, as always, the problem. Have you included all of Rodrigo's units? I am still amazed that anybody contemplates such a bug ridden feature.

Comment: @David To no avail. Adding `Vcl.Styles.Fixes` from that library has no effect on this bug.

Comment: Well your choice. Use the MS code and your program works or use the Emba code and it doesn't.

Comment: Does using vcl styles bring you increased revenue?

Comment: @David Compared to the boring UI it was before, yes :-)

Comment: How odd. My experience is that users fork out for functionality.

Comment: I had Seattle running, so I did a quick test, and I can't reproduce it. Steps I took: File->New->VCL Forms App, Project->Options->Application->Appearance->Windows 10 Dark, made sure combobox at bottom reflected that style, close the dialog, run. Checked with app in default state - OK. Minimize and check again - OK. Move mouse over preview image (still minimized) - saw image of non-minimized form in its normal position. Restored - OK.

Comment: If it can't be reproduced then it's off topic I guess.

Comment: So is everyone judging on one person's inability to reproduce the issue? Or are the close votes based on multiple attempts? As noted in my question, this problem occurs on 4 completely different Delphi installations.

Comment: And why a close vote as not providing code? There is zero code. Empty application. Am I really expected to post the code of an empty application?

Comment: Also funny how someone deletes relevant comments but not the irrelevant ones.